# Finding the distribution of $X-Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

The joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is given by,

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$ if $0<x<2,0<y<1,2y\leq x$

Find the pdf of $U=X-Y$.

**My attempt:**

To solve the above, I consider the transformation $(X,Y)\rightarrow (U,Y)$.

$0<x<2,0<y<1\implies -1<u<2$

Again $2y\leq x \implies x-y\geq y \implies u\geq y>0$

So,$max(0,-1)<u<2 \implies 0<u<2$

Now, $x=u+y$

$0<x<2 \implies 0<u+y<2 \implies -u<y<2-u$

Again, $2y\leq x \implies 2y\leq u+y \implies y\leq u$

So, $max(0,-u)<y<min(2-u,u,1)$

$\implies 0<y<min(2-u,u,1)$ as $u>0$

$\implies 0<y<u$ when $u\in(0,1)$ and $0<y<2-u$ when $u\in(1,2)$

Jacobian of transformation is:

$J=J(\frac{x,y}{u,y})=\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}=1$

So, joint pdf of $(U,Y)$ is:

$f_{U,Y}(u,y)=f_{X,Y}(u+y,y)|J|$

$=1$,     $0<u<2$ and $0<y<u$ if $u\in(0,1), 0<y<2-u$ if $u\in(1,2)$

So, marginal pdf of $U$ is:

$f_{U}(u)=\int_0^udy=u$ if $0<u<1$

$f_{U}(u)=\int_0^{2-u}dy=2-u$ if $1<u<2$

But I am not sure whether this is correct or I have messed up with the ranges. I have not found any illustration on distribution of function of two 'dependent' random variables when I searched. So I want to confirm this is the right approach. Any suggestion will be accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $Z = X-Y$ (potential)support of r.v is $(0,2)$. let $z \in (0,2)$

$$p_{Z}(z) =P(X-Y =z) = \int_{y=0}^{y=1}p(X-Y=z , Y=y)  dy$$

$$ \hspace{4.0cm}= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} p(X = z+y , Y=y) dy$$

here if we use the fact that $0< X=z+y < 2 \implies -z < y < 2-z$  and using the fact that $0<y<1$ hence $0 < y < \min\{2-z,1 \} .$ and

we have to again use the fact that $2.y \leq x$ (here $x=z+y$ look at joint prob inside integral) $2y \leq z+y $ from which we have that $y \leq z$ and now we update our inequality on right size $0 < y < \min\{2-z,1,z\}$

$$ \hspace{6.0cm} = \int_{y=0}^{y= \min\{2-z,1,z\}} p(X= z+y , Y=y) . dy $$
$$ \hspace{4.0cm}= \min\{2-z,1,z\} $$

and we are done.

sometimes it is best you try to compute in brute-force way

Edit: Added justification about support of z

$x-y\geq x- x/2 = x/2 \geq 0$

Comment: How can you be sure that the lower bound of $y$ is $0$? Shouldn’t it be $max(0,-z)<y<min(2-z,1,z)$?

Comment: @user587389 allowed values are of z on $(1,2)$ otherwise it is zero

Comment: Isn't it $z\in (-1,2)$? Even you have written this in the second line.

Comment: I have made a error before that it was written that range of r.v z is (1, 2)

Comment: @user587389 check now

Comment: we know that $2y \leq x \implies  x-y \geq 1$ otherwise your joint density is zero.

Comment: If $x=1,y=0.4$, then $x>2y$, but $x-y<1$. I still don't get how to determine the range of $z$.

Comment: @user587389 sorry, I was thinking x's lower bound is $2$. So possible support is $(0,2)$ now look at the end of the answer.